# Kotlin generics anomaly

Tags: android, generics, kotlin

Ok, so I have three interface types.

1. `Movement<T : Animal>`
2. `Animal` with subinterfaces `Cat`, `Dog`, `Horse`
3. `AnimalMovement`

**Movement Interface**

```
interface  Movement<T : Animal> {
    fun moveAnimal(type:T)
}
```

**Animal Interfaces**

```
interface Animal {
    fun takeSteps()
    fun jump()
    fun hide()
}

interface Cat : Animal
interface Dog : Animal
```

**AnimalMovement**

```
interface CatMovement : Movement<Cat>
```

I then implement the CatMovement interface

```
class CatMovementImpl : CatMovement {
    override fun moveAnimal(type: Cat) {
        TODO("not implemented")        
    }
}
```

**Problem**

```
fun TestGenerics() {
    var catMovement : Movement<Cat> = CatMovementImpl() // this works
    var catMovement : Movement<Animal> = CatMovementImpl() // this doesn't?
}
```

I am sure in Java both lines would have worked fine. However in Kotlin the second line fails to execute. Why would that be? An animal is the base type for cat, so this should have worked right?

Comment: I am pretty sure that doesn't work in Java either. A `Movement<Cat>` is NOT a subtype of `Movement<Animal>`, the same way a `List<String>` is NOT a subtype of `List<Object>`. You might want to read [this](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html).

Comment: Should it be `out Animal`?

Comment: m0skito you seem to be right.

Answer (score 2):

I am not an expert of Kotlin, but that seems perfectly normal:

When declared like this:

```
var animalMovement : Movement<Animal>
```

You can write code:

```
animalMovement.moveAnimal(dog)
```

But if assigning it like this:

```
var animalMovement : Movement<Animal> = CatMovementImpl()
```

is allowed, it means that your `CatMovementImpl` should be able to move a dog ?

Comment: I can see where my logic is flawed. This and m0skito's comment under the question perhaps shed some light. I am revisiting the task at hand

Answer (score 1):

What [moskito](https://stackoverflow.com/users/898478/m0skit0) said in the comments is correct.

> I am pretty sure that doesn't work in Java either. A `Movement<Cat>` is
>   NOT a subtype of `Movement<Animal>`, the same way a List is NOT
>   a subtype of `List<Object>`. You might want to read this.

But in Kotlin this is possible using type variance.

```
fun TestGenerics() {
    var catMovement1: Movement<Cat> = CatMovementImpl()
    var catMovement2: Movement<out Animal> = CatMovementImpl() // works
}
```

You basically tell the compiler "accept all implementations of `Movement<Animal>` or implementations `Movement<S>` for which `S` has `Animal` as upper bound".

But, then a problem arises. You cannot invoke

```
val cat: Cat = /* ... */
catMovement2.moveAnimal(cat) // error
```

giving you the error

> Out-projected type `Movement<out Animal>` prohibits the use of [...].

because `T` can only be used as producer (out position) and not as consumer (in position) like this (function made up to demonstrate the point):

```
val c: Cat = catMovement2.getAnimal() // works
```

This problem becomes clear right away when you  use `out` at the `Movement` declaration like this:

```
interface Movement<out T : Animal> {
    fun moveAnimal(type: T) // error
}
```

---

It depends on your use case but maybe you should just let Kotlin infer the type, which would be `CatMovementImpl`.

```
var catMovement = CatMovementImpl()
```

<sub>Credit goes to [EpicPandaForce](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2413303/epicpandaforce) for already suggesting using `out` in the comments.</sub>

Comment: I would just add that you can't call `moveAnimal` on a `Movement<out Animal>`, making it pretty useless for this interface in particular.